# How to check the app icon is put on the homepage for iOS system?

Tags: ios

I want to check if the user has put my app's **icon is on the homepage**.
How to check it.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm just taking a wild guess here... It's not possible.

Comment: You can't. There is no API for it.

Comment: Just a question: where do you expect your app icon to be located... if not on the home screen? Inside a folder? In the quick access bar at the bottom of the home screen? And: why does this matter to you?